# XML transformation

Tags: xml, transform

I have the below xml sheet:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1256'?>
<tc>
<tt>
    <sd>112</sd>
    <sN>Good Day</sN>
    <id>468629</id>
   </tt>
   </tc>
```

Which i want to convert to as below:

```
<Tada schemaVersion="2" xmlns:ge="ST" xmlns:gl="TS" xmlns:ga="SG">
<ge:test internalID="90566" dateAdded="2013-03-19T11:49:28" lastEdited="2013-03-    20T16:26:49" >
   <ge:TN="World" internalID="161634" />

  </ge:test>
</Tada>
```

I have cut them both short, as they are very long files. But the idea here is to convert from first xml to second xml. Now how do I put this line: schemaVersion into my final output, The rest of the items should be easy to tranlate / match. I would try them with the XPath commands. I tried using XSLT as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <Tada schemaVersion="2" xmlns:ge="ST" xmlns:gl="TS" xmlns:ga="SG">
    <xsl:template match="/">

 <Title>
            <xsl:value-of select="//tt/sd"> </xsl:value-of>

      </Title>

    </xsl:template>
     </tada>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But in my test above it doesnot write out : the schema version line, instead it types out the whole file as follows:

```
112
Good Day
468629
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

This seems to work here is what I did:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
      <xsl:template match="/">
 <Tada schemaVersion="2" xmlns:ge="ST" xmlns:gl="TS" xmlns:ga="SG">
 <Title>
          <xsl:value-of select="//tt/sd"> </xsl:value-of>

   </Title>
</tada>

</xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm using oxygen, why it doesn't show identated to the left. Instead it gives me output all in one line. How to fix this.

EDIT:

Solved by adding the following :

```
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
```

This gives me a new line